# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}n}$ continuous?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, continuity, fourier-series

Considering the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}n}$ , I can show that  it is not convergent uniformly by Cauchy's criterion and that it is convergent for every $x$ by Dirichlet's test.  But I don't know how to judge whether it is continuous.

Could you tell me the answer and why? Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you show convergence by Dirichlet's test? For example if $x=1$ it isn't alternately positive then negative...

Comment: $1/n$ is decreasing and the partial sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{sin(nx)}$ is bounded. So the sum of the product is convergent.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks, and +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: Is it somehow obvious that the partial sums of $\sum \sin(nx)$ are bounded?  I'm not seeing it...

Comment: @JasonDeVito It is the imaginary part of a geometric series.

Comment: @achille:  Awesome - thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To inspect the discontinuity of the summation, let's calculate the sum. By the Abel's theorem,

$$ f(x) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n} = \lim_{s\to 0^{+}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n} e^{-ns}. $$

By utilizing Taylor expansion of the logarithm,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n} e^{-ns}
&= \Im \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{n(ix-s)}}{n}
 = - \Im \log (1 - e^{ix-s}) \\
&= -\Im \log (1 - e^{-s}\cos x - ie^{-s}\sin x) \\
&= \arctan \left(\frac{e^{-s}\sin x}{1 - e^{-s}\cos x}\right).
\end{align*}

Thus taking $s \to 0^{+},$

$$ f(x) = \arctan \left(\frac{\sin x}{1 - \cos x}\right) = \arctan \left(\cot \frac{x}{2}\right) = \arctan \left(\tan \frac{\pi-x}{2}\right). $$

Therefore

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\pi - x}{2} & x \in (0, 2\pi),\\
0 & x = 0, \\
f(x+2\pi), & x \in \Bbb{R}.
\end{cases} $$

This shows a clear-cut jump discontinuity at each $x \in 2\pi \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: I rethink this question today.And I observe that if we drop out "$e^{-ns}$",the proof can still work,in other words, for $x\neq0$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n}
&= \Im \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{nix}}{n}
 = - \Im \log (1 - e^{ix}) \\
&= -\Im \log (1 - \cos x - i\sin x) \\
&= \arctan \left(\frac{\sin x}{1 - \cos x}\right).
\end{align*}   
And if $x=0$  ,the summation is $0$.

Comment: @F.G Tha ks for pointing out that. I was also aware of that, but I adopted this regularizing method in order to avoid possible problems arising from the boundary behavior and the convergence mode of the series.

Comment: What is that J symbol?

Comment: The "J" symbol is a fancy I, and it means the imaginary part

Answer (score 1):

Another way to prove that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$ is discontinuous at the origin (and so at every element of $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$).
If $f(x)$ is a bounded function and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$ does exist, it equals $\lim_{m\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x)m e^{-mx}\,dx $ (approximation of the identity). Due to
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(nx)m e^{-mx}\,dx = \frac{m n}{m^2+n^2} $$
we have
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} = \lim_{m\to +\infty}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{m}{m^2+n^2} $$
and by Riemann sums the RHS of the last line equals $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{2}\neq 0$.