# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin nx}{n}$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

So I came across this series  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin nx}{n}$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$. The problem is to find all $x$ for which the series is uniformly convergent. Now, I am struggling to answer that question. My understanding was that $0$ and $\pi$ are the only points. But I cannot prove it, can someone please give me any ideas/hints?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know what you mean by uniform convergence for a specific $x$, but I think for $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, you get the sum $1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\dots$ which I think is $\frac{\pi}{4}$, so other $x$'s do work.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the question stated as "for which values of x does the series converge uniformly".

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28830/does-sum-frac-sinnxn-converge-uniformly-for-all-x-in-0-2-pi

Comment: And also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566856/is-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sinnxn-continuous